# Acknowledgements do not format properly in latex

Tags: formatting, align, acknowledgements

I'm writing my PhD thesis in Latex. The following formatting is required: declaration-blank page-acknowledgements-blank page-chapter. If my acknowlegments are a single page everything appear correctly but because my section is a bit longer than a page it does not format correctly. It appears as declaration-blank-"acknowledgments" written at the bottom of the page - acknowledgments - chapter.

This is the code to define the acknowledgments in the .cls file

```
\newcommand\acknowledgements[1]{ 
\btypeout{Acknowledgements} 
\addtotoc{Acknowledgements} 
\thispagestyle{plain} 
\null\vfil 
\vskip 60\p@ 
\begin{center}{\Large\bf Acknowledgements \par}\end{center}
{\normalsize #1} 
\vfil\vfil\null 
\cleardoublepage 
}
```

How do I define more than one page in this section?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Is the requirement really to have a blank page, or rather to have the next chapter start on an odd-numbered page (the right hand page in an open book)? In your case: 1 - declaration, 2 - blank, 3 - acknowledgement, 4 - acknowledgement continued must be followed by either zero or two blank pages if the chapter is to start on an odd-numbered page, but not by one.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered without more information (e.g. what the declarations section and chapter starts do). Please post a complete example code that enables others to reproduce the problem.